# Pymongo Find & Update problems

Tags: mongodb, flask, pymongo

**Background**
I'm making an application which takes an input through a Discord bot and then puts the input in a Google Document. During that process, I'm using Flask with Pymongo to find documents whose `isNew` property is set to `true` and send it back to Google Docs script. After that's done I want to set the `isNew` property of the documents to set to `false`. Alternatively, I can set the `isNew` to `false` before I send, since i can't call a function successfully, after I have returned the response in Flask.

Based on what I've experimented with, whenever I get new documents using a `<CollectionName>.find()` request, and tried to update the `isNew` property subsequently using a `CollectionName.update_many()` command, it results in the variable storing the original `find` command documents to go blank.

Code Attempts:
1. update many while trying to return new documents

```
import pymongo

# mongodb db connection string
connectionString = ('mongodb://localhost:27017')

client = pymongo.MongoClient(connectionString)
db = client['tempBotDB']

# 3 types of questions: quiz, cross, hunt
# separate collections for each type of strings

quizQs = db['quizQs']
crossQs = db['crossQs']
huntQs = db['huntQs']

# Properties of a question: isnew, type, question, answer


def saveQ(qObj):    # Saves a question to the db

    qType = qObj.get('type')

    # creating own qObj
    q = {
        'question': qObj.get('question'),
        'answer': qObj.get('answer'),
        'isNew': bool(True)
    }

    if qType == 'quiz':
        result = quizQs.insert_one(q)
    elif qType == 'cross':
        result = crossQs.insert_one(q)
    elif qType == 'hunt':
        result = huntQs.insert_one(q)
    else:
        result = ('Error: "type" of question can only be'
                  'one of : cross, hunt, quiz')
    return result


def getQs(qType):   # Gets all the questions by given type
    if qType == 'quiz':
        result = quizQs.update_many(
            {'isNew': bool(True)},
            {'$set': {'isNew': bool(False)}},
            {returnOriginal: True}
         )
        print(result)

    else:
        result = ('Error: "type" of question can only be'
                  'one of : cross, hunt, quiz')


getQs('quiz')
```

Error: NameError: name 'returnOriginal' is not defined
Also tried with `returnNewDocument` instead of `returnOriginal`. But got: `NameError: name 'returnNewDocument' is not defined`

2. Using a find followed by an update within the same function

```
def getQs(qType):   # Gets all the questions by given type
    if qType == 'quiz':

        selector = {'isNew': False}
        modifier = {'$set': {'isNew': True}}

        result = quizQs.find(selector)
        #fakeRes = quizQs.update_many(selector, modifier)

        print('res', result)
        for i in result:
            print('result', i)
        #print('fakeres', fakeRes)
        # for i in fakeRes:
        #     print('FakeRes', i)

    else:
        result = ('Error: "type" of question can only be'
                  'one of : cross, hunt, quiz')
```

If I uncomment the `update` command, the result of the `find` command becomes uniteratable (I get an error message), which to the best of my knowledge means that it's empty. Here's what happens:

```
def getQs(qType):   # Gets all the questions by given type
    if qType == 'quiz':

        selector = {'isNew': False}
        modifier = {'$set': {'isNew': True}}

        result = quizQs.find(selector)
        fakeRes = quizQs.update_many(selector, modifier)

        print('res', result)
        for i in result:
            print('result', i)
        print('fakeres', fakeRes)
        for i in fakeRes:
            print('FakeRes', i)

    else:
        result = ('Error: "type" of question can only be'
                  'one of : cross, hunt, quiz')
```

I get an the following output:

```
res <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x10e34ca50>
fakeres <pymongo.results.UpdateResult object at 0x10e35bfa0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "db.py", line 63, in <module>
    getQs('quiz')
  File "db.py", line 55, in getQs
    for i in fakeRes:
TypeError: 'UpdateResult' object is not iterable
```

Notice how iterating through the `result` object did not print anything, pointing to the fact that it goes empty.

So, to conclude, my main question is: 
How do I successfully find and update multiple documents in mongodb, while retrieving the update documents, OR just the found documents (not updated) [EITHER of them will work as i won't need to access the property I update]

Lastly, would it be logical to first do a `find` and then `update_one` on each document while generating a list of dictionaries of the updated documents and then finally returning that list to the user?

I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. Added the code snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few ways to do this, but you can't get the list of updated documents from an update_many - Mongo doesn't support that.

So your best approach is:

```
for record in db.mycollection.find({'isNew': False}):
    result = db.mycollection.update_one({'_id': record['_id']}, {'$set': {'isNew': True}})
    print(record)
    # Add in logic here  to assemble records for return to the user
```

Comment: Note for implementation:
The ```record```'s isNew field will remain ```true``` while printing the ```record```. It is updated, but just not changed in the ```result``` object. Which works for my case, but you might want to check that for your context of implementation.